# Customising Users - Add attributes or claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using the new Identity 2.0 in my MVC project, and I want to add a few custom fields to user accounts. I've only just started to use it, so I'm still getting to grips.

The fields will need their values to be stored in the database, and I'll also need to be able to access these custom fields in the main part of the app (not just in the account controller), and also I need to know that these values haven't been tampered with (as they'll be generated when the user registers).

Given these requirements, should I just add the fields as attributes into the ApplicationUser class, or should these fields be claims?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the answer.

Claims are things which identify the user i.e. "My username is X", "My email address is Y",
"My password hash is Z" etc... These are things which you get from "trusted sources".

So the thing I need is custom attributes, as these custom fields don't identify the user.